# while function is not working during the interactive looping in python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

First, see my code.

```
    coordinates_length = 0
    while coordinates_length != 2:
        cor_list = []
        DataCursor(scat, index, depth)
        plt.show()
        coordinates_length = len(cor_list)
```

What I tied to do was 'interactive' looping.
In the plot, I pick the two coordinate and based on the number of picks that I choose, the plot show again or follow the next step.

It works, when I picked the two coordinates and smoothly follow the below code.
However, if I picked more than two or less than two, some error occurred.

It seems the codes are just following the endless looping.

How can I correct this code??

Comment: Please update your question with the full text of the error that occurred.

Comment: Your code is a bit minimal (you probably exaggerated your [mcve]). Where does `cor_list` get updated in the loop? As long as it does not change, this code will loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--------Update by author----------

Theoretically, there was no error in the code in the question.
Rather, It seems, there was a problem with plotting.

The original code was:

```
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        ax.invert_yaxis()
        ax.axvline(x=firstimg, color='red', linestyle='--')
        scat = ax.scatter(index, depth, s=7, c= 'grey')


        coordinates_length = 0
        while coordinates_length != 2:
            cor_list = []
            DataCursor(scat, index, depth)
            plt.show()
            coordinates_length = len(cor_list)
```

And then I changed the code:

```
            coordinates_length = 0
            while coordinates_length != 2:
                fig = plt.figure()
                ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
                ax.invert_yaxis()
                ax.axvline(x=firstimg, color='red', linestyle='--')
                scat = ax.scatter(index, depth, s=7, c= 'grey')
                cor_list = []
                DataCursor(scat, index, depth)
                plt.show()
                coordinates_length = len(cor_list)
```

like this.
And it works.